# "Bool *" from "int" makes pointer from integer without cast?

Tags: c, pointers, boolean, warnings, hashtable

I keep getting this warning in my compilation of the following code saying that *"assignment to ‘_Bool *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast"** at "`*result = true;`" and I have no clue what it means. How can I solve this? It passes all my tests.

[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FiT8.png)

```
char *hash_table_lookup(hash_table_t *ht, int key, bool **result)
{
  /// Find the previous entry for key
  entry_t *tmp = find_previous_entry_for_key(&ht->buckets[key % No_Buckets], key);
  entry_t *next = tmp->next;

  if (next && next->value)
  {
    *result = true;
    return (next->value);
  }
  else  
  {
    *result = false;
  }
}
```

It is tested in the following manner

```
void test_lookup1()
{
   hash_table_t *ht = hash_table_create();
   char *valtest = "a";
   int keytest = 12;
   hash_table_insert(ht, keytest, valtest);
   bool *result;
   hash_table_lookup(ht, keytest, &result);
   CU_ASSERT_TRUE(result);
   hash_table_destroy(ht);
}
```

Comment: Your `result` argument is a double pointer (`bool **result`) so `*result` is a pointer (`bool*`). You are trying to assign `false` or `true` (both *integral* types in C, if you're using the `<stdbool.h>` header) to that pointer. For a formal/fuller answer (including a fix), we would need to see more code, like what you do with the `result` argument and what you pass as that argument.

Comment: `result` is a pointer to a pointer. When you dereference it with `*result` you're still getting a pointer to `bool`, to which you're assigning an integer. Why does `result` hneed to have type `bool **`?

Comment: At the moment, my "best guess" would be that the two `**` is a typo ... but that's *only* a guess.

Comment: Why does that `result` variable need to be a pointer? Surely you want a straight `bool` return value as the pass/fail signal, and just pass a `bool* result` to the function?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead directly copy&paste your text (code, input and output) into the question.